# TeXpad and R code

Tags: texpad, compiling

I am trying to get TeXpad (latest OSX-version) to compile a document with some R code, but just ends up with errors. This is my first try

My document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document}
    You can type R commands in your \LaTeX{} document and they will be properly run and the output printed in the document.
 <<>>=
 # Create a sequence of numbers X = 2:10  
 # Display basic statistical measures summary(X)   
 @ 
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `xelatex` (or `pdflatex`) and preprocessed R code, either with Knitr or Sweave, it ends up without the R code being recognised. Is this not possible with TeXpad?

Comment: People might not be familiar with texpad. Does compilation work from a terminal? That is first knitr or sweave of this file, the pdflatex on the output from knitr or sweave

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution to my problem: When I renamed the file with extension .Rnw it compiled like it should.